# nextKeyView is not working

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nstextfield, nsresponder

I have developed an application, which has one tableview and 4 textfields.

When I run the app, the control is not going orderwise by giving TAB. For that I set `initialResponder` as tableView, then connected tableview's nextKeyView to textfield, correspondingly I had given connection for rest of the fields. But still the control is not going orderwise.

What is the problem? Did I missed something? Or is there is other way to do it?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a screenshot of the contents of your nib, including both the outline in Xcode and the interface as it will appear to the user.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Full Keyboard Access set to "All controls"?  If it is set to "Text boxes and lists only" then tabbing may not move focus between your controls.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the window's **Auto Recalculates View Loop** is unchecked in the inspector.

Then play with ctrl+F7, which toggles how the tab key works system wide. One mode tabs from text field to text field, the other tabs to all controls.